# How to test a JAX-RS @POST

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

How do I test a @POST method?

It's easy to test @GET because all you need to do is access the URL, how do I do this for @POSTs? Do I need to actually perform a form submit?

Comment: There are many different ways of doing it, from `curl -X` to writing your own HTML page and clicking on "submit". You need to be more specific if you want an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically? Something like [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html):

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

// Send data
URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/urltopostto");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
```

Interactively? You can use SoapUI (the free edition) to do [REST Testing](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html)

[image]

Comment: interesting app you suggested there :) Will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Theres also quite a few REST extensions for Chrome.  I use [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb?hl=en-US).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool like rest-client (http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) to test all RESTFull WS

Answer (score 0):

The curl tool (http://curl.haxx.se/) is also very useful here.

curl -i -X POST -v  --data-urlencode 'key=value' will send a Post with key=value as post data.